# Flavor of Linux which is ONLY command line (and super light-weight)?

Tags: linux, command-line, usb

I'm looking to install an extremely light-weight flavour of linux on a USB stick. It also needs to be basically only CLI. Has anyone ever looked for something like this? Ever found something good?

Comment: If you don't want to go from scratch, Gentoo is also a good start.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To be particularly minimal, you could roll your own.  Fair warning: this is an endeavor of many hours, but you'll better appreciate what goes into getting your OS pieced together.

Linux From Scratch is a very actively maintained step-by-step guide on just that:
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/

Comment: wow this is awesome! I'm definitely going to be going through this. Great learning experience.

Answer (score 9):

Red Hat or Debian are probably what your looking for. You could also install Ubuntu as command line only.

Comment: Visited this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD and trying that. Thanks

Comment: This suggestion is wrong. Red Hat and Debian are built to support a wide range of software configurations. They are anything but minimal.

Answer (score 4):

MicroCore is a command-line only variant of [Tiny Core Linux](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/).

Comment: Tiny Core Linux is awesome.

Answer (score 3):

[ttylinux](http://freecode.com/projects/ttylinux/) is extremely lightweight and CLI only --  [busybox](http://www.busybox.net/) utilities built off of uclib.

Comment: NOTE: "ttylinux, as of September 2015, has been discontinued until a new maintainer comes forward. The home page no longer exists." (http://linux.wikia.com/wiki/Ttylinux)  An old release can temporarily be downloaded here, although this site has not been maintained in over 2 yrs: http://freecode.com/projects/ttylinux/

Answer (score 2):

Back in the day there was Linux On A Floppy (LOAF) and [Tom's Root Boot](http://www.toms.net/rb/). However I suspect they are **too** super light weight for USB drives :-)

Nowadays I suppose the equivalent is [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) which will install onto a bootable USB flash stick.

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu Server](https://www.ubuntu.com/server) might be what you are looking for. Because servers are usually headless, the basic setup does not contain any GUI parts.